# How to get data in vue template by call a function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have multiple stores. These shops sell a variety of products. A list of shops should be displayed on the page, as well as a list of the categories of products that a shop sells.

[Console.log data in coming but I can't display Store product Category pare list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzjq9.jpg)

```
   <template>               
        <div class="store">
            <div v-for="store in stores" :key="store.id" :set="products = getProducts(store.id)">
<h2>{{store.name}}</h2>
//Other Store info
<ul>
<li v-for="product in products">
{{product.category.name}}
//This data is not Show
</li>
</ul>

             </div>
        </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                stores: []

            }
        },
        mounted() {
            var app = this;
            axios.get('/axios/allstore/')
                .then(function (response) {
                    app.stores = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
        methods: {
            getProducts(storeID) {
                var pp = this;
                axios.get('/axios/storeproducts/' + storeID, {
                        params: {
                            storeID: storeID,
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        return response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        },
    }

</script>
```

Thanks, Advance.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: also, are we supposed to guess how your objects in the array look like? ;) Please post sample data.

Comment: I no. Store list show well but :set vareable data not Show. I have console data show please see include img.

Comment: yes, but what does the array contain, more specific, how does an object look like? What properties do they have?

Comment: At what point do you set the `products` values?

Comment: I flow this Technic https://codepen.io/mmghv/pen/dBqGjM?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=f2dffb5639e533b86e6052ad15ca44b791e43279-1580224433-0-AX2RiDf7Y6DMreI7DgBhwQ97TlweNRf5HJ02YsndIRN-tNvqTOJTK968Xkzf5xrDWPny_WbKfAeUUMNlHJ579Ww4aOyKkL0KNZbRcA9XzpqXLCNOMgHmV7VG5JaTWftnbfr04HtHWya7gPGDYDyMPXMQiMGs9zL2DR8Ewp1SxRdUSxBuuoin4BJlecpc24QYfgdxLjgsuGs-37QEITlW_u9e6Dnm-A1KB8ypx14IaFIauRo-rIQ1JnUbLdHnjmwZ_XLraQEFFpxOYKWfrDjQruhBjSKLiGPRmABYpXN756nhqfiXoELr-VLNbILxG2jqABkvh2mN0zBs2lAHdbsWrY8

Comment: products values in set for loop <div>

Comment: You have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a completely different approach, since first of all, using `:set`, your http-requests would be fired whenever change detection happens. Instead gather all the data when component is rendered:

```
created() {
  this.getStores();
},
methods: {
  getProducts(id) {
    return axios.get("...")
      .then(response => response.data)
  },
  getStores() {
    // first get stores, you can also use async await instead, if you like
    axios.get("...").then(response => {
      this.stores = response.data;
      // gather all requests for each store to get products
      const reqs = this.stores.map(store => this.getProducts(store.id));
      axios.all(reqs).then(products => {
        // merge data
        this.stores = this.stores.map((store, i) => {
          return { ...store, products: products[i] };
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Now, for each store, there is a `products` property:

```
<div v-for="store in stores" :key="store.id">
  <h2>{{store.name}}</h2>
  <ul>
    <!-- choose a key, here just using index -->
    <li v-for="(product, index) in store.products" :key="index">
      {{product.category.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As for the template, make sure that `category.name` actually exists in the product object.